# Using Graph API without a logged in user

Tags: facebook-graph-api, offline

I'm very newbie on using Graph API and I have just read about the future deprecation of offline_access permission and that's a problem for me.

I know I have a very bad English, but I will do my best for explain me. I hope you can understand me.

As far as I know, when you send a request for some FB info and you pass an access token for being able to act on behalf the user that "gives" you that token (I am asking the users for authorizing my app with the client-side flow and then I store the access token for future requests) and there is no user logged in FB, an error ocurrs and the request fails.

In my case, when I send the info request to FB it's impossible that a user is logged in FB (I don't know how to explain the reason in English, but it is no possible). So, until know, I am using tokens with the offline_access permission and then I can send the requests on the behalf of that users that authorizes the app for offline access.

What I want to know is if that it's going to be impossible from know that offline_access permission is going to be deprecated. I mean, I want to know if there is a solution that let me send requests on the behalf of a user without him being logged in FB (I need an access token that survives to a logout of that user after he gives the app authorization).

Sorry for my bad English and I hope you will be able to understand me.

---

I will try to make my question in a better way:

What I want to do is an app that the user access from a TV and there is no browser available for use. Because of that, I don't know how I can redirect the user to FB for authenticate and authorize the application. So, what I do is prepare a "configuration website" where users can go and authorize the app for offline use (redirecting them to FB and asking them for offline permission). I store the offline tokens and then, when the users access the app I can make Graph API requests with those tokens and I can get FB info even If there is no a user log in FB (there is no browser or something else where a user can log in Facebook).

From now, offline_access permission is going to be deprecated. So... How can I make a Graph API call without a logged user and without a offline_access permission?

I tried to use the new endpoint to get a new token when I receive the error that say that a token is not valid because the user logged out from FB, but the response of the this endpoint is exactly the same: The token that I send with the new request is not valid because the user logged out and I am not able to get a new token if the user don't log in again. But I can't redirect the user to FB for log in each time he access the app, due to the fact that the user don't use a browser.

Answer (score 0):

No, your access tokens shouldn't expire after user logs out. Access tokens will expire after certain amount of time, but you can silently extend them for 60 days each time user interacts with your application: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
If what you say in your answer is correct I am doing something wrong but I don't know how.
I activate the migration option "Deprecate offline access:" on my app configuration. Then I do this test:
1) I connect to my app for authorizing the app (without offline_access permission, because it is deprecated). The app stores the obtained token.
2) I logout from Facebook, for testing if the token can survive the logout.
3) I do a request to FB info using the token obtained in step 1, and the FB answer tolds that the token is invalid because the user logged out. What's wrong?

Comment: You're using client-side OAuth, I guess. Read the section "_Client-side OAuth and Extending Access_Token Expiration Time through New Endpoint_" from the link above, it should help.

Comment: Yes, that section was the first I think it's going to help me. But I try to use that new endpoint and the error still occurs. If I have an access token without offline permission (because It has going to be deprecated) and then the user logout from FB and I try to make a request with that token, the "user has logout" error occurs, and if I try to send a request to that endpoint for extending this expired token, I obtain the same error as answer (it say me that the token is not valid because the user logged out).

Comment: I guess, you could either use server-side authentication or extend the access token expiration time immediately just as you create them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but I can't make it work yet... I use server-side authentication now: I obtain the code by redirecting the user to FB for authorizing the app and then I use "/oauth/access_token" endpoint for obtain an access token with this code. I store that access token but when the user logout and I send a Graph API request, it fails and the answer is "...The session is invalid because the user logged out". I can't understand how I can send a Graph API request from my server with a user logged in FB, because I have no cookie as the user's browser has...

Comment: I have just resolve the problem... I don't know why but the problem was my app configuration in FB. I activated the migration option about deprecation of offline permission. But I think something was wrong, because I have make a new FB application and using the AppID and AppSecret from this new app the server-side authentication works fine. Now I am able again to make Graph API request without a user logged in FB just in the moment of the request! Thank you very much for your help!